# SpriteKit How to Slowdown Game with RepeatForever Actions continuously running, similar to Matrix Dodging Bullets Effect?

Tags: ios, skaction

I'm trying to slow down my `_gameLayer` Node by 0.5 when the player collected a slowing down timer and I want to see all the nodes inside `_gameLayer` running at a much slower speed.

However when I use the code `SpeedTo`, it resets my laser to its original position and restarted it's SKAction movement, which makes the game look jerky and doesn't make sense.

What I want to achieve is like the famous Matrix dodging bullet clip: watch from 0:19 https://youtu.be/xZ0OUq_kDh8

```
[_gameLayer runAction:[SKAction speedTo:0.5 duration:1.0]];
```

Below is one of example of nodes inside my `_gameLayer`.

```
SKAction * resetToOriginalPosition = [SKAction runBlock:^{
       laser.position = CGPointMake(200,400);
    }];

[_gameLayer addChild:laser];

[laser runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveByX:0 y:-400 duration:2.0],resetToOriginalPosition]]]];
```

What do you think the issue is?